# Unable to fetch .json file from Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am able to fetch a .txt file but not a .json file getting a 404 with .json file

Update
After doing some more research I beleive this problem has a lot in common with the issue here

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/africaapps/2013/06/07/how-to-serve-static-json-files-from-a-windows-azure-website/

but now for web apps

Comment: Your question lacks any indication or clues as to what the issue could be, so it's very difficult to help. Can you add any details around how you're doing this? How are you verifying that the file is there?

Comment: @MarkC.  Thank you for your response.  I can verify the file is on in the Azure web app environment via the Console and the App Service Editor.  For testing, I am using my browser console and just using the fetch command.  I am able to change the .json file to a .txt file through the App Service Editor and it starts working

Comment: Yes, but if the file accessible via the Web App in the Azure Web App environment?  You're just trying to fetch the file using browser hitting up a URL?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm attempting.  it's working for .txt files but not .json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I added web.config like the linked suggests.  Didn't immediately occur to me to do that because web.config seem more associated with .net vs the node server I'm using to server my SPA